# How to resolve XMEMORY Error in Borland C++ builder Code?

Tags: c++, c++builder, vcl, c++builder-xe

I am using Embarcadero C++Builder XE.

When I build `XMLWrapperLib.lib` in a VCL project, I get an error:

> [BCC32 Error] xmemory(28):E2285  Could not find a match for 'SmartXMLWrapperNode::auto_ptr(const SmartXMLWrapperNode)'

If I click on the error, it goes to xmemory file code, Template function.
point to below:

```
::new (_Vptr) _T1(_Val);
```

I have copied some files inside this folder:

[rtl100/120/150.bpl  and vcl100/120/150.bpl, vclx150.bpl, xmemory]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\RAD Studio\8.0\include\dinkumware

But it still gives me the same error.

Comment: It is clear from the error message that `_T1` is `SmartXMLWrapperNode::auto_ptr` and `_Val` is a `SmartXMLWrapperNode` object rather than a `SmartXMLWrapperNode*` pointer. What does the actual definition of `auto_ptr` look like?  It likely doesn't accept a `SmartXMLWrapperNode` object as input. Smart pointer wrappers are usually constructed from pointers instead. The compiler output should show you the complete call chain leading up to the `auto_ptr` construction (if not, enable more detailed output in the settings). Follow the calls to the source, there is likely a bug in the code somewhere.

Comment: It is resolved by Reinstalling 1) RAD XE then 2) Dev Express again. Also i have copy XMemory file inside C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\RAD Studio\8.0\include\dinkumware

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was error of Multilizer setup. After Installing it it is resolved.